# API - use GET to add, edit, and delete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, rest

I'm building an API and want Ajax to be able to interact with it. The API needs to allow inserting, updating, and deletion of data. Is it a good idea to allow any of these operations via GET?

For example: http://api.domain.com/insert_person/?name=joe

My original plan way to use GET for my "getting" methods (basically, just a simple DB query) and POST for add, edit, and delete. Problem is JS same-origin policy which would make it hard for Ajax to interact with my API. There is a jQuery workaround for GET (via JSONP).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word: NO

GET should always be used only for retrieving information and should never have side effects, ever.

This is a best practice across just about every web api out there and has to do with both  the intent of the verb as well as how existing software expects things to behave.

Comment: What do you think about using POST for inserting, updating, and deleting?

Comment: that's pretty much the only option in most browsers, though modern ones are starting to support PUT and DELETE verbs.  Generally, following the verbs is a good idea unless you have constraints preventing it, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get around the same origin policy, GET via JSONP is the only possible front-end solution. If you've got control of the back end you can setup a proxy service that is on the same domain as the page, but relays to and from the API service.

If you're going to go down the JSONP GET path, make sure you read up on XSS and CSRF.

Comment: can you elaborate on the proxy service? I'm not sure about how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add another layer of to handle your code and interact with your database (different domain).

You would still use POST and you can make a request to your db in the server side, using what ever language your are working with, example php will use curl.(to make request to a different domain)

If you allow to interact with your db using get, then anyone can simply type the url with the commands they want, so yes avoid it .

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, GET should not be used for actions with side effects like inserting, updating and deleting.

To allow cross-origin use of your API, look into [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), although it's currently [only partially supported by browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=cross-origin).